# Are text files, pictures, sound files and video files all stored/transferred as stream of bytes?

Tags: java, .net, stream

What else are represented as stream of bytes?

Comment: I can't think of anything that *can't* be stored as a stream of bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a certain level of abstraction, just about everything is stored, represented or transferred as a sequence or stream of bytes.

> Ok, what can be stored/transferred as a System.IO.Stream object in .NET or counterpart in Java?

Any information that can be represented by a computer can (in theory) be turned into a sequence of bytes and stored / transferred via a byte-oriented I/O stream.  You may need to write some software to transform the computer representation of the information into a sequence of bytes that is suitable for transfer via a byte stream.  However, *any* finite representation can be transformed into bytes.

The only things that you cannot represent and transmit as a byte stream are those that only have an infinite representation (e.g. the complete value of Pi, or the set of all prime numbers), and those that have no digital representation (e.g. beauty or Barack Obama).

---

> Ok, what can be stored/transferred as a System.IO.Stream object in .NET or counterpart in Java?

I don't know about the .NET case, but Java's `ObjectOutputStream` only works for classes that implement the `Serializable` or `Externalizable` interfaces.  (And in the former case, all other classes in the non-transient closure of the original object must also implement `Serializable`.)

Some system classes are not `Serializable`; for example, Thread, Process, various IO classes and most AWT / Swing related classes.  The common theme is that that these classes all involve some kind of resource that is managed by the operating system.

Comment: Ok, what can be stored/transferred as a System.IO.Stream object in .NET or counterpart in Java?

Answer (score 1):

This may be more of a philosophical matter, but anything that you can *think of objectively* can be stored as a sequence of *numbers*. Bytes are just one example, but you can store them as a sequence of numbers, text characters (because [they are also translatable to numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)), peanuts on a table, ***anything.***

For example, you can represent the same thing as either bytes or hex digits themselves represented as decimal numbers and the characters A, B, C, D, E and F right? such as

```
#nav{color:#123ABC;}
```

You can also [Base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) anything, and Base64 means there are 64 possibilities. You could make up Base65 if you wanted to, and it would work too.

Then what can be represented? What can you think of? What can you define rationally? All that can be thought can be represented as a stream of numbers - every file in our hard drives is one after the other in a huge stream, the concept of "folders", "files", etc. is just an abstraction of offsets in that huge chain of ones and zeroes that we interpret as bytes, ints, chars, etc.